# Why won't gulp run through MSBuild in Develop configuration?

Tags: jenkins, npm, msbuild, gulp, msbuild-task

I have a project which uses a gulpfile.js, and have set it to run gulp before build:

```
<Target Name="GulpBuildDevelop" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Develop'">
        <Exec Command="npm install gulp" />
        <Exec Command="gulp build-development" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="GulpBuildUAT" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='UAT'">
        <Exec Command="npm install gulp" />
        <Exec Command="gulp build-release" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="GulpBuildRelease" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
        <Exec Command="npm install gulp" />
        <Exec Command="gulp build-development" />
    </Target>
```

I am building using MSBuild on the Jenkins server, running on push.  All the projects are on the same server, just different directories.  In UAT and Release everything runs as expected:

```
    GulpBuildRelease:
  npm install gulp
  
  up to date, audited 959 packages in 3s
  
  62 packages are looking for funding
    run `npm fund` for details
  
  11 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 8 high, 2 critical)
  
  To address issues that do not require attention, run:
    npm audit fix
  
  To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
    npm audit fix --force
  
  Run `npm audit` for details.
  gulp build-development
  [[90m10:51:43[39m] Using gulpfile C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Records.calfee.com-Live\workspace\ApplicationUI\gulpfile.js
  [[90m10:51:43[39m] Starting 'build-development'...
  [[90m10:51:43[39m] Starting 'js-vendor-dev'...
    ...[abbreviated]...
    [[90m10:51:54[39m] Finished 'css-vendor-dev' after 11 s
  [[90m10:51:54[39m] Finished 'kendo-vendor-dev' after 11 s
  [[90m10:51:54[39m] Finished 'js-app-dev' after 11 s
  [[90m10:51:54[39m] Finished 'build-development' after 11 s
```

However, in the Develop branch, the install runs differently and it errors saying it cannot run gulp:

```
GulpBuildDevelop:
  npm install gulp
  npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
  npm notice save gulp is being moved from devDependencies to dependencies
  npm WARN Invalid version: "1.0.0.0"
  npm WARN ApplicationUI No description
  npm WARN ApplicationUI No repository field.
  npm WARN ApplicationUI No README data
  npm WARN ApplicationUI No license field.
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\sass\node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
  
  + gulp@4.0.2
  updated 1 package and audited 1421 packages in 4.453s
  found 10 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)
    run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
  gulp build-development
  'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried running npm install -g gulp, tried specifying the working directory, nothing has worked.